# Unsynchronized way to write on Bluetooth on BluetoothChat example

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

This is the first time I'm involved on a bluetooth's based app on android and for understanding better how it works, I'm studing the BluetoothChat example.
More or less, I think I'm understanding everything, but I've come to a point I can't go any further.
What's the reason for writing data this way?

```
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}
```

Why not calling mConnectedThread.write(out) directly?
And what's the target of this synchronize?

I understand (obviously wrongly) this code is only executed on the main thread and in this case, why do we need this mutex?

Thanks to all.
P.S.: Sorry for my poor English!

Answer (score 0):

For the question part: ***And what's the target of this synchronize?*** - objective seems to be accessing mThread and mConnect variables in a thread safe way (i.e. no change in other variable while one is being accessed). This link (and additional links therein) will through more light on [Java Synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321747/java-synchronization)