# Does synchronized on methods make other threads that try to access that method wait until it is executed?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait

I just wanted to know if Thread1 adds elements to a list with a synchronized method and Thread2 tries to add elements to the same list does Thread2 wait until Thread1 has finished adding its elements or does it just check and if it can't access the method then it doesn't even bother trying to add elements to the list anymore?

Thank you!

Comment: You could just try it...(or read the documentation)

Comment: Cave of programming have good videos on youtube where he does explain multithreading :) i recommend.You will learn how to even make your own locks.And that way understand all this better

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Synchronization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321747/java-synchronization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread2` will wait.

I suggest you to read the o[fficial documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) about this topic it is rather thorough.

If you do not want to worry about this problem try the data structures in the java **concurrent** packages.

Comment: It isn't a typical situation that can cause a deadlock. A deadlock requires two methods that both call each other, or three or more that form a circle of calls, or another use of 'synchronized' on an object. A single synchronized method alone cannot possibly cause a deadlock.

Comment: @ejp theoretically you can load a class with different classloaders which means that the "same" method will have different locks.. ok I'll leave myself out,  sorry but I couldn't resist the nitpicking ;)

Comment: @EJP I guess you were the one who downvoted: If `Thread1` calls a synchronized method which works on a shared object and the process takes forever then `Thread2`'s call will lead to a deadlock since it can't do its work on it. Excerpt from wikipedia: "Mutual Exclusion: At least one resource must be held in a non-sharable mode.[1] Only one process can use the resource at any given instant of time."

Comment: @Adam The scenario you're giving is not a deadlock (or a livelock or any kind of lock really). Thread1 is making progress the whole time after all.

Comment: You can argue on terminology but the fact **stays the same** that `Thread2` is blocked indefinitely.